# Spring MVC: Controller function not getting called on form submit

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, controller

I am new to using Spring MVC framework and have designed a html page which has two forms. One is login(form id: loginform) and other is for signup((form id:signupform). The controller is being called correctly for the login page but for the signup, nothing happens (no controller is called) and the page just refreshes. I am not able to find out the source of the problem. Here is my JSP page:

Login.jsp

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@page session="true"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
 crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp"
 crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
 integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
 crossorigin="anonymous">
 
</script>
<spring:url value="/resources/css/mylogin.css" var="mainCss" />

<link href="${mainCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
<%--  <link href="<spring:url value='/resources/css/mylogin.css'/>" rel="stylesheet"> --%>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div id="loginbox" style="margin-top: 50px;"
   class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
   <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <div class="panel-title">Sign In</div>
    </div>

    <div style="padding-top: 30px" class="panel-body">
     <c:if test="${not empty error}">
      <!--  Invalid Username Password -->
      <div class="error">${error}</div>
     </c:if>
     <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
      <!--  Logged out successfully -->
      <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
     </c:if>
     <div style="display: none" id="login-alert"
      class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>

     <form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form"
      name="loginform"
      action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>

      <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i
        class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span> <input id="login-username"
        type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value=""
        placeholder="username">
      </div>

      <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i
        class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span> <input id="login-password"
        type="password" class="form-control" name="password"
        placeholder="password">
      </div>

      <div style="margin-top: 10px" class="form-group">
       <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
        <input class="btn btn-success" id="btn-login" name="submit"
         type="submit" value="LOG IN" /> <input type="hidden"
         name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-md-12 control">
        <div
         style="border-top: 1px solid #888; padding-top: 15px; font-size: 85%">
         Don't have an account! <a href="#"
          onClick="$('#loginbox').hide(); $('#signupbox').show()">
          Sign Up Here </a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="signupbox" style="display: none; margin-top: 50px"
   class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
   <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <div class="panel-title">Sign Up</div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     <form:form id="signupform" class="form-horizontal" role="form"
      method="POST" modelAttribute="userForm"
      action="<c:url value='/adduser' />">
      <div id="signupalert" style="display: none"
       class="alert alert-danger">
       <p>Error:</p>
       <span></span>
      </div>

      <form:hidden path="id" />

      <spring:bind path="name">
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-md-3 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
         <form:input path="name" type="text" class="form-control"
          name="name" placeholder="Name" />
        </div>
       </div>
      </spring:bind>

      <spring:bind path="email">
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="col-md-3 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
         <form:input path="email" type="text" class="form-control"
          name="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
        </div>
       </div>
      </spring:bind>

      <spring:bind path="username">
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username" class="col-md-3 control-label">Username</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
         <form:input path="username" type="text" class="form-control"
          name="username" placeholder="Username" />
        </div>
       </div>
      </spring:bind>

      <spring:bind path="password">
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="col-md-3 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
         <form:input path="password" type="password"
          class="form-control" name="passwd" placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
       </div>
      </spring:bind>

      <spring:bind path="dob">
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="date" class="col-md-3 control-label">Date of
         Birth</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
         <form:input path="dob" type="date" name="bday"
          class="form-control" />
        </div>
       </div>
      </spring:bind>
      <spring:bind path="image">
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pic" class="col-md-3 control-label">Profile
         Picture</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
         <form:input path="image" type="file" name="pic"
          class="form-control" />
        </div>
       </div>
      </spring:bind>

      <spring:bind path="genreName">
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="genre" class="col-md-3 control-label">Favorite
         Genres</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
         <!-- <input type="file" name="pic" class="form-control"> -->
         <form:select multiple="" path="genreName" name="genreNames"
          class="form-control">
          <c:forEach items="${genres}" var="genre" varStatus="ctr">
           <option id="${genre.id}" value="${genre.name}">${genre.name}</option>
          </c:forEach>
         </form:select>
        </div>
       </div>
      </spring:bind>

      <div class="form-group">
       <!-- Button -->
       <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
        <input class="btn btn-info" id="tn-signup" name="submit"
         type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-md-12 control">
        <div
         style="border-top: 1px solid #888; padding-top: 15px; font-size: 85%">
         Already have an account? <a id="signinlink" href="#"
          onClick="$('#signupbox').hide(); $('#loginbox').show()">
          Sign In </a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </form:form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```html
package com.moviebase.web.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.moviebase.web.model.user.UserDao;
import com.moviebase.web.model.genre.Genre;
import com.moviebase.web.model.genre.GenreDao;
import com.moviebase.web.model.user.User;

@Controller
public class MainController {
 
 @Autowired
 public UserDao userDao; 
 @Autowired
 public GenreDao genreDao;

 @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/welcome**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView defaultPage() {

  ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
  model.addObject("title", "Moviebase");
  model.addObject("message", "This is default page!");
  model.setViewName("hello");
  Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
     String username = auth.getName(); //get logged in username
  User user = userDao.findByUsername(username);
  System.out.println(user.toString());
  return model;

 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/admin**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView adminPage() {

  ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
  model.addObject("title", "Moviebase");
  model.addObject("message", "This page is for ROLE_ADMIN only!");
  model.setViewName("admin");

  return model;

 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
   @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {
  
  ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
  if (error != null) {
   System.out.println(" error:"+error);
   model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
  }

  if (logout != null) {
   model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
  }
  
  List<Genre> genreList = genreDao.getAllGenres();
  model.addObject("genres", genreList);
  
  User user = new User();
  model.addObject("userForm", user);
  
  model.setViewName("login");

  return model;

 }
 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/adduser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ModelAndView createUser(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User user,
   BindingResult result) {
  
//  ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
//  model.setViewName("redirect:/");
  System.out.println("Came here");
  userDao.insert(user);
  return new ModelAndView("redirect:/admin");

 }
 
 //for 403 access denied page
 @RequestMapping(value = "/403", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView accesssDenied() {

  ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
  
  //check if user is login
  Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
  if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
   UserDetails userDetail = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
   System.out.println(userDetail);
  
   model.addObject("username", userDetail.getUsername());
   
  }
  
  model.setViewName("403");
  return model;

 }

}
```

Web.xml

```html
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

 <display-name>MovieBase</display-name>

 <!-- Spring MVC -->
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
   /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
   /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml
  </param-value>
 </context-param>

 <!-- Spring Security -->
 <filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
 xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>database</groupId>
 <artifactId>moviebase</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>Moviebase</name>

 <properties>
  <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
  <spring.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
  <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
  <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
  <mysql.connector.version>5.1.30</mysql.connector.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>

  <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Spring Security -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Spring Security JSP Taglib -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- jstl for jsp page -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>jstl</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>${jstl.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
  </dependency>

 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <finalName>moviebase</finalName>
  <plugins>

   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>${jdk.version}</source>
     <target>${jdk.version}</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>

   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
     <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
     <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
     <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>

  </plugins>
 </build>

</project>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.moviebase.*" />

 <bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix">
   <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
  </property>
  <property name="suffix">
   <value>.jsp</value>
  </property>
 </bean>
 
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

</beans>
```

Comment: in the log, is there something that show the error ?

Comment: There is no error in the log.

Comment: try and let me know action="j_security_check"  instead of action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" for both form apply same approach

Comment: Can you provide your `User` model class? Perhaps the `@ModelAttribute` in your `createUser` method can not be bound/mapped correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your singup form has the http method POST but your controller is form http method GET

Your JSP:

```
<form:form id="signupform" class="form-horizontal" role="form"
                        method="POST" modelAttribute="userForm"
                        action="<c:url value='/adduser' />">
```

Your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adduser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView createUser(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User user,
            BindingResult result) {
```